# scrollToRowAtIndexPath last cell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am scrolling the table programatically to display last cell. but table display only half of last cell.So to see last cell I have to scroll it manually.`[tblBuddyMessageList  scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];`

Comment: As you are requesting to move the cell to the middle, it is odd that it cannot be seen. Any chance you are using the wrong indexPath? What happens if you use `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom`. The cell at the bottom will be the one you passed the index path for. It is also possible that your scroll view is off the bottom of the screen. In the debugger print the frame for the tableview. if its bigger than the screen height then thats your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that there is something wrong with the content size of UITableView. Set proper constraints to the Bottom Layout Guide or check if you don't have any value (Constant field) in the constraint provided.

Another option is to bind a height constraint to an IBOutlet of UITableView and set the proper value in the runtime.

Comment: NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"tblBuddyMessageList":tblBuddyMessageList};
        
        NSArray *constr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[tblBuddyMessageList]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
        
        [self.view  addConstraints:constr];  Do you see any problem in this . ? Please let me know.

Comment: It looks ok. Maybe try to add also height constraint for tblBuddyMessageList and set the proper height. Also it's good to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO.